# Active Directory - ß vs. ss

Tags: microsoft-excel, active-directory, special-characters

I'm trying to unify the `streetaddress` attribute of our users. In German, the character `ß` can also be represented as `ss`.

Some users have `Examplestraße` as `streetaddress` value, while others have `Examplestrasse`.

I'm trying to list all users with `Examplestraße` (note the `ß`), but it seems that this is not possible:

```
Get-ADUser -server domain.example.com -properties StreetAddress -filter "Streetaddress -eq 'Examplestraße'"
```

This lists both users with `ss` and `ß` in the attribute. The same issue affects the AD Users & Groups "Find" function.

Excel does the same if I try to filter the columns. This is driving me mad. How can I enforce a "strict" matching of these characters?

Comment: Just a remark: I remember that there are specific rules about when to write "ss" and when to write "ß". So one is wrong. Are you trying to filter on wrong results?

Comment: For these tools apparently `Examplestraße` and `Examplestrasse` are already equivalent. So what is the point of unifying them "more"? Is there *another* tool for which they are *not* equivalent? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Also, if what you used "lists both users with `ss` and `ß` in the attribute", does it really prevent you from unifying? Can't you just assign the desired value to all of them? For some this will be a change, for some this will be a no-op. What is the practical problem?

Comment: @Dominique yes, I am trying to filter "wrong" results.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The practical problem is that there is a third-party software connected via LDAP, which is *not* following this convention. And yes, while "just set it for all" would be a viable approach, I'm still curious as how to avoid this. The same "rule" seems to affect umlauts aswell.

Comment: You could perhaps export the entire list to a file, then use a tool or a text editor that handles it better.

Comment: *"Excel does the same if I try to filter the columns. "* What did you use to filter? Formula, or manual? What happened, what did you expect it to do? How can we reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

While the filter in `Get-ADUser -Filter` looks like PowerShell syntax, internally it's translated to an LDAP filter. As far as I know, the LDAP implementation within Active Directory does not support any of the usual "extensible match" rules that would allow overriding the behavior of server-side LDAP filters (not that you could use this via Get-ADUser anyway).

So you'll have to start by taking what the server gives you and then applying a *local* PowerShell filter to narrow it down further:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "StreetAddress -eq 'Examplestraße'" | `
    Where-Object { $_.StreetAddress -eq "Examplestraße" }
```

Here the second `-eq` *is* done locally by PowerShell and is a "dumb" string comparison, so it will not match `strasse`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had to swap the second `-eq` for a `-match` to get the desired result - with `-eq` it still reported `Examplestrasse`. Oh, and `Get-ADUser` does support `-LDAPFilter`, but no extended matching filters. Feel free to update, and I will accept the answer :)